# resolve queries using using a route 53 private hosted zone from aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I'm starting to think it's not, but is it at all possible to have an aws api gateway resolve its forwarding requests using a private route53 hosted dns zone?

Cheers

Comment: The API Gateway service does not run inside your VPC. Route53 private hosted zones only work inside the VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you definitely can't at this time. Closest you can get is using lambda to proxy the request like so https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Its possible now with VpcLink on AWS Api Gateway.

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit more info, I've tried a VPC Link and I'm still unable to resolve private hosted DNS entries on the same VPC.

I get the "Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI" error